# this.setState is not a function when using the arrow function

Tags: react-native

The `console.log` prints out the correct numbers, but `this.setState` throws errors.  I thought I was binding it correctly using the arrow function.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.emotion='happy';
  this.state = {
      idList:[]
  };
 }

componentWillMount() {
 this.getEmotionIDs();
}


getEmotionIDs = () => {
   firebase.database().ref(this.emotion).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("IDs: " + snapshot.val());
     this.setState({ idList: snapshot.val()});

  });
}   


render() { 

   return (
 ....
  )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Using arrow functions for your promises for auto binding

```
getEmotionIDs = () => {
   firebase.database().ref(this.emotion).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("IDs: " + snapshot.val());
     this.setState({ idList: snapshot.val()});

  });
}
```

Comment: 'This' is the toughest part in javascript, still i have trouble in that. Hope u master it through asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `bind` in `getEmotionIDs` too:

```
getEmotionIDs = () => {
 firebase.database().ref(this.emotion).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("IDs: " + snapshot.val());
    this.setState({ idList: snapshot.val()});

    }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: well, I tried that and keep getting the error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({ idList: snapshot.val() })', 'this.setState' is undefined)